# Two integrals based on measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$$\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{\int_{0}^{\infty}}\frac{n\sin\frac{x}{n}}{x(1+x^2)}dx$$

$$\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}}\frac{\arctan(n\left\|{x}\right\|)}{(1+\left\|{x}\right\|^2)^2}dx$$

Could anyone to help me in this two integrals? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: there is a powerful theorem involving interchanging limits and integrals. Does it apply here, and if so, what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Dominated integration

For the first integral for instance using the fact that $|\sin y|/|y|\leq 1$ for all $y$ (with the convention is $\frac{\sin y}{y}=1$ for $y=0$), one gets

$$
\frac{n\sin\tfrac{x}{n}}{x(1+x^2)}\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

As $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n\sin\tfrac{x}{n}}{x}=1$ for each $x$, by dominated convergence

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_0\frac{n\sin\tfrac{x}{n}}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx =\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\arctan(x)|^\infty_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$

For the second integral, notice that $|\arctan(y)|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ and that $\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. I leave the  remaining details to you.

Comment: Thankyou Very much! and how can I delimit the arctan in the second integral? do I need any special equality?

Comment: Notice that $|\arctan(y)|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $y$ and that $\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. To estimate the limiting integral, you may use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Following Integrand's comment and  Oliver Diaz' suggestion for the second limit, it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{\arctan(n\|x\|)}{(1+\|x\|^2)^2}\,dx&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{dx}{(1+\|x\|^2)^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int^\infty_0\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^2}\,d\theta\,dr\\
&=\pi^2\int^\infty_0\frac{r\,dr}{(1+r^2)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{2r\,dr}{(1+r^2)^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{2}\frac{1}{1+r^2}\Big|^\infty_0=\frac{\pi^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thankyou very much! I have understood. So I´ll try more integrals to practise.

Comment: But the integral is in R^2, not from 0 to ∞

Comment: @Gray: I just edited my solution. My thoughts were faster than my typing.